# How do I run a Ruby script on Linux and have the name of the script show up in TOP COMMAND instead of Ruby?

Tags: ruby, linux, gitorious, top-command

I have a bunch of scripts that run periodically as part of Gitorious, they all show up in `top` under `command` as `Ruby` how do I get them to show the actual script name that is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hit the letter 'c' while top is running, it toggles display between command name and line